# CSS Animation leaves stray pixels behind

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-animations, web-frontend

I'm trying to achieve a simple "Underline on hover" animation on my navbar links. The animation, however, leaves stray pixels behind after the animation is complete, as shown in the below GIF.

[Underline animation leaves stray pixel to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAIky.gif)

The weird thing is, it does not happen if I hover the cursor between two links having the same animation. It happens only when I hover on a link and then move my cursor elsewhere.

[The bug doesn't happen while hovering between navbar links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09uY4.gif)

I have implemented the navbar as follows:-

```
<div class="nav-bar-flex">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Company</a>
      <a href="#">Careers</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-bar-flex a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: -0.055rem;
}

.nav-bar-flex > a::after {
     content: "";
     display: block;
     width: 0%;
     border-bottom: 2px var(--secondary-orange) solid;
     margin-top: 0.3rem;
     transition: width 300ms;
}

.nav-bar-flex > a:hover::after {
     width: 100%;
     transition: width 300ms;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the `letter-spacing` property on the `anchor` tags is causing some kind of calculation error for the rendering engine which causes it to leave a stray pixel.

So there are two solutions I was able to come up with:

**Solution 1:**

Use transform to do it like so:

```css
.nav-bar-flex > a::after {
     content: "";
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     border-bottom: 2px var(--secondary-orange) solid;
     margin-top: 0.3rem;
     transition: transform 300ms;
     transform: scaleX(0);
     transform-origin: left;
}
.nav-bar-flex > a:hover::after {
     transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Remove `letter-spacing` from the `anchor` tags.

By the way, since you have transition on the actual element you do not need to have it again on the hover event.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Vio! **Solution 1** indeed worked out for me. However removing the `letter-spacing` did not change anything. The stray pixel was still there. I'm still curious as to what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Add opacity to after and its transitions

```
.nav-bar-flex a {
  display: inline-block;
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 1rem;
   font-weight: 400;
   letter-spacing: -0.055rem;
 }

.nav-bar-flex > a::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px var(--secondary-orange) solid;
  margin-top: 0.3rem;
  transition: width 300ms, opacity 300ms;
```

}

```
 .nav-bar-flex > a:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
   transition: width 300ms, opacity 300ms;
}
```

Working solution: https://codepen.io/aledebarba/pen/zYNzOrL

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ale Macedo! I had implemented this workaround earlier. But I did not like the "Fade out" effect this causes when the mouse is hovered off of the link. I am still curious as to what is causing the bug.

Comment: I looked around for some similar questions and found this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/17723401/8441606] about how webkit could make some mistakes while rendering the DOM. A possible solution is to add 'transform: translateZ(0);" to force webkit redraw the element "with attention".