# Why does a small glitch (pixel dot) sometimes appear below a menu item when using this hover effect?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

It is barely noticable but sometimes a small dot appears, like the one below the "prices" menu item:

[image]

This is the hover effect I wrote:

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar > li + li {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.navbar > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: .5em 0 .05em;
  color: #0e9daf;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar > li > a::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: currentColor;
  transition:
    left .4s ease-out,
    right .4s ease-out;
}

.navbar > li > a.active::after,
.navbar > li > a:hover::after {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu-slide-center.css">
  <title>Menu Slide from Center Effect</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

I've noticed the same in Chrome and Firefox as well. Any idea how can I fix that?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this in the snippet (in either chrome or safari) but would guess that it's because the `left:50%, right: 50%` rules on `a::after` are running into rounding errors.  Maybe cheat and set them both to 51%?

Comment: I do see that happening on Products in the snippet on Chrome. If I scroll vertical the dot disappears.

Comment: Daniel Beck- Yes, thank you, setting both to 51% worked fine.

Comment: @Daniel Beck I managed to fix it by using `scaleX` instead of percentages and absolute positioning. Changing the percentage value did not work no matter how much I bumped it up.

Comment: @ZoltanKing Glad you found a better solution! the 51% thing was pretty hacky, I probably shouldn't have suggested it.  

If you wouldn't mind, please revert the edit to your question that includes the answer -- it tends to be confusing to future readers if answers are mixed in with the question text. Instead you can post that as an answer below, where it can be upvoted etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue was rounding errors due to percentage values as Daniel Beck pointed out in this thread.

I managed to fix it by using a different approach, instead of absolute positioning and percentage values I decided to use `scaleX` which provides the same visual effect but without the glitch.

```
.navbar > li > a::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: currentColor;
  transition:
    transform .5s ease;
  transform: scaleX(0);
}

.navbar > li > a.active::after,
.navbar > li > a:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Comment: Yes, might be related to the explanations found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983520/webkit-animation-is-leaving-junk-pixels-behind-on-the-screen/17822836 or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575624/how-can-i-avoid-animation-artifacts-on-my-touch-draggable-border-radius-element/17723401#17723401 the usual solution to issues like this is forcing hardware acceleration like you did with scaleX

Answer (score 0):

It must have to do with rounding issues, as already said. One way to make sure that dot doesn't appear is to add `width: 0` and `width: 100%;` to the two states, and change `transition` to `all`:

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar > li + li {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
}

.navbar > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: .5em 0 .05em;
  color: #0e9daf;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar > li > a::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: currentColor;
  transition: all .4s ease-out;
}

.navbar > li > a.active::after,
.navbar > li > a:hover::after {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu-slide-center.css">
  <title>Menu Slide from Center Effect</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```